# Common code for multiple angular4 modules

Tags: angular, intellij-idea

We have a situation in my company where in a single Intellij project there are multiple angular4 modules. In all these modules there is common code that is currently being duplicated, for example:

1. Angular components (and other angular artifacts like directives and services).
2. Assets - like images and fonts.
3. Dependencies - like bootstrap (and others) in their node_modules.

My question is how can we rearrange the modules so that we will have a common place (like a common intellij module in the same project, maybe?) so that all the common code will reside in?

Obviously, the editor must still continue to suggest completions correctly (both from the specific module and the common module), and webpack should continue building correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate static web module for the common part. But note that  types resolving between Idea modules only works in dependent modules: each of your angular modules should have a dependency on *common-module* to get functions from *common-module* resolved. The only way to create a dependency on static web module is adding a **JavaScript library**: in `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries`, `Add...`, `Add files`, choose the *common-module* directory that includes functions you'd like to refer to, then in `Manage scopes` dialog make sure to attach this library to the module that refers to the function.

Another option is adding this common folder as a separate content root to each of your web modules: `Project Structure | Modules`, select your module, `Add content root`, choose the folder where your common code resides.

> webpack should continue building correctly.

Webpack knows nothing about IDEA modules/project structure, it deals with paths.

Comment: The second option of adding the common module folder as a content root is not applicable since Intellij forbids it. Taken from the error dialog that appears: "Two modules in a project cannot share the same content root".